# Using terminal to sort data and keep the format in notepad.exe

Tags: windows, bash

I'm using Ubuntu Bash within Windows 10 and I have a text document with:

```
{u'osidjfoij23': 3894798, u'oisjdao':234567, u'oaijsdofj': 984759}
```

using tr, in terminal I change my output to

```
'osidjfoij23': 3894798,
'oisjdao':234567, 
'oaijsdofj': 984759}
```

when opening the same document via notepad.exe, the newline "\n" added from tr doesn't register and all the data gets presented as a paragraph.

I know this is because bash and notepad have different encodings for their documents, is there a way to make these work together or an alternative I can use for notepad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unix2dos` to convert a file to Windows line endings. Linux programs handle Windows line endings fairly well, so this shouldn't break anything (especially if that's JSON as it appears to be).

Comment: was worried for a second because dos2unix was all that was showing up in apt-cache, but I saw it came bundled with unix2dos as well. Just tried it out and works exactly like I needed. Thank you!